# Android textview ellipse removes the html content

Tags: android, html, textview, ellipse

I want to show html content in a textview also if its more than 5 lines then trim the additional lines and add "..." at the end. I used these code to add a trim the additional lines,

```
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(message));

this.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.ALL);
this.setMaxLines(5);
this.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
this.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
```

but it worked only for for some texts,

```
        ViewTreeObserver vto = feedListRowHolder.description.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                ViewTreeObserver obs = feedListRowHolder.description.getViewTreeObserver();
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                else obs.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

                if (feedListRowHolder.description.getLineCount() > 5) {
                    int lineEndIndex = feedListRowHolder.description.getLayout().getLineEnd(4);
                    String text = textview.subSequence(0, lineEndIndex - 3) + "...";
                    textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
                }
            }
        });
```

the issue is it removes html format from the text.

Answer (score 0):

Change this    `String text = textview.subSequence(0, lineEndIndex - 3) + "...";`

to   `String text = message.subSequence(0, lineEndIndex - 3) + "...";`